# RandomizedSearchCV object has no attribute .best_estimator_

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

#AttributeError: 'RandomizedSearchCV' object has no attribute 'best_estimator_'#

[* Block of code, does not run, error included in image*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1jBD.png)

my variables and custom objects have been defined in blocks prior

Comment: I think you need to call `rf_random.fit()` first. See here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/71767/randomizedsearchcv-object-has-no-attribute-best-estimator

Comment: can you show where you called `RandomizedSearchCV` and please do not post images

Comment: please show how you have defined rf_random. It's easier if you include the code here instead of the image as well.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.